# juju ERROR Unable to connect to environment "maas"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

whether i do juju status or destroy-environment or bootstrap i am getting the error

ERROR cannot connect to API: unable to connect to "wss://10.1.1.187:17070/environment/f41f9bb1-c503-4a7b-81c0-07fa221f8a4e/api"

10.1.1.187 is the IP that was used by juju while bootstrapping that MAAS node....it is the IP for juju-br0 on the juju bootstrapped server......I can ping that IP from MAAS server........This preventing from installing openstack or to deploy an juju service........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$ juju destroy-environment maas --force`, then bootstrap again.

If it doesn't help, share maas log file (/var/log/maas/maas.log)

Comment: did try juju destroy with force ...still getting the error below......2016-05-04 16:55:38 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 gomaasapi: got error back from server: 504 Gateway Timeout (<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"......The system cannot communicate with the external server (&nbsp;170.23.134.56&nbsp; --this is MAAS IP) and lastly .... 2016-05-04 16:32:54 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1 .....Thank you

Comment: share log files i /var/log/maas/ please

Comment: First ....Thank you for your reply.....it helped....Also there are no errors in maas log but the issue resolved with the steps below....updating proxy in environment.yaml ....specially the no proxy settings ...... here is the correct format .... Proxy settings in environment.yaml under
 openstack:
        type: openstack

        juju set-env http-proxy: http://my.proxy.com:80
        juju set-env https-proxy: http://my.proxy.com:80
        juju set-env no-proxy:localhost,10.1.1.0/24,170.16.115.128/26  Also by updating maas-region controller IP to the PXE interface IP.........

Comment: Good to hear your problem resolved, and thanks for providing your solution. It will help me or someone in future.